# How to check is RabbitMQ connection is used in other places

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Good afternoon! 
I use RabbitMQ connection as Singleton. 
So, for example, the first form opens and creates connection, the second - get the created instance of the connection. 
And in the method CloseConnection I want to check - if a connection is not used anywhere - to close it. In another case - do not close the connection. How can I check this? I didn't found any properties in IConnection to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure using a singleton is the best thing to do, but I'll try to answer you anyway.

Consider a class variable `count` in your singleton. Each time your code get a reference to your singleton, increment the counter. Each time your code wants to close the connection, decrement the counter. If the counter equals zero, close RabbitMQ connection.